# How to print webpages with iframe and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have to print the contents of a dialog. I'm adding a empty iframe then i add contents to it in javascript.

this is my js code where i add html and css as children of iframe

```
    var layoutCSS = new String('<link href="css/ReportPageOne.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    var pageOneCSS = new String('<link href="css/ReportLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    var pageTwoCSS = new String('<link href="css/ReportPageTwo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    var materialityCSS = new String('<link href="css/MaterialityMatrix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    window.frames.print_frame.document.head.innerHTML = layoutCSS + pageOneCSS + pageTwoCSS + materialityCSS;
    window.frames.print_frame.document.body.innerHTML = $('#__dialog1-cont').html();
    window.frames.print_frame.window.focus();
    window.frames.print_frame.window.print();
```

opens the print dialog properly but css is not applied quite well.

On print page in options i checked in 'Background graphichs' and i am using google chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `frame.print()` before the styles have loaded.

"The load event fires once the stylesheet and all of its imported content has been loaded and parsed, and immediately before the styles start being applied to the content."

Try this:

```
head.lastChild.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    // In IE, you have to focus() the Iframe prior to printing
    // or else the top-level page will print instead
    frame.focus();
    frame.print();
}, 0);
```

**References**

- https://github.com/abbotto/teleprint/blob/master/src/components/print.js
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that all the CSS was loaded, just the last one, they may finish out of order

Comment: My reasoning is that CSS files are loaded in the order in which they are included. When the last stylesheet has loaded, print the frame.

Can you provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I was wrong, there is never a guarantee that the four CSS files requested will come back in order but the load event won't fire until after it's parsed. In that case, then it's guaranteed to wait even if downloading the last CSS finishes before the first. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events. `The load event fires once the stylesheet and all of its imported content has been loaded and parsed, and immediately before the styles start being applied to the content.`

Comment: I've added your feedback to the answer, thanks for clarifying things.